# Latex documentations has Too many arguments

Tags: latex

```
\section{CA code}
\subsection{
[Generate the C/A code for the three satellites PRN A, PRN B and PRN C (see table below)
```

following the description in the `ICD200K`, `p.29ff` together with table `3aI, p 4/5.\par`

Crosscheck the first 10 chips of each of your generated codes with table `3-1` in the GPS interface specification `(IS-GPS)`. Plot first 20 chips of the codes.]}

*I am writing report and getting error like Too many arguments. What is the error ?*

Comment: Please make a [mre] which allows us to reproduce the error

Comment: Don't put the whole paragraph in the subsection, only the title

Comment: \section{CA code}
\subsection{
[

 (IS-GPS). Plot first 20 chips of the codes.]}

Comment: Same issue in the above section also, but here we can resolve it by deleting space or new line key. But over there it is not possible.

Comment: Problem occur when I have been having only one blank line or putting \par command to give new paragraph.

Comment: 1) please add the code (starting with a documentclass and ending with `\end{document}`) in your question, as you can see comments won't show important stuff line linebreaks 2) why are you using a new line or `\par` in the **title** of the subsection? Putting the whole subsection into the title is not what it is made for.